# Using .split to isolate undefined keyword in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, environment-variables

I'm taking an image, running it through pytesseract to get a list of text, and saving that list as a variable:

```
img = Image.open(path_to_some_image)
imgtxt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(imgtxt)

>> Some text here
keyword
Random strings
Random chars
```

My challenge is getting `keyword` without defining it, as it changes depending on when the program is run. I've found that `keyword` always follows `Some text here`, whereby `Some` and `here` are always constant, and `text` fluctuates between two words, so I split the output at `here`. Now, I get the following:

```
print(imgtxt.split("here",1)[1])

>> keyword
Random strings
Random chars
```

This removes everything before `keyword` without defining it, but now I'd like to remove everything after. My question, then, is how could I remove `Random strings` and `Random chars` without making `keyword` into a variable?

Comment: Are `keyword`, `Random strings` and `Random chars` in separate lines? And can you post a more specific example, instead of using `Random strings`, `Random chars`?

Comment: @GaneshTata Yes -- they appear exactly as entered. Here is the actual output: `cars` blank line break `Duck venfy once there Ire none 1th`. I'd like to get the word cars. The issue is that `cars` will not always be the same word; however, it will always appear after the the word `here`, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @mod So, `Some text here`, `keyword`, `Random strings` and `Random chars` are all in different lines? Which means that they are all separated by `\n`, right?

Comment: @GaneshTata That is correct. I could specify a line number to get `keyword` without defining it, but -- like the name that `keyword` takes -- it's not consistent; it's not always in the same position. The only thing that remains the same is that it follows the word `here` on a new line. I also tried getting its index, and it fluctuates between 113 and 23 depending on which photo I pass into `pytesseract.image_to_string(img)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the split one more time, but this time get the first item:

```
imgtxt.split("here", 1)[1].strip().split("\n", 1)[0]
```

Works for me:

```
In [1]: imgtxt = """Some text here
        keyword
        Random strings
        Random chars"""
In [2]: imgtxt.split("here", 1)[1].strip().split("\n", 1)[0]
Out[2]: 'keyword'
```